# How to get subcategoriy ids in recursive mode for other record maping using postgres?

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

```
category_id | category_name | category_parent_id
3           | All           |   NULL
4           | Stationary    |    3
5           | Food          |    3
6           | Solid         |    5
7           | Liquid        |    5
8           | Soft Drinks   |    7
9           | Pepsi         |    8
10          | 7up           |    8
11          | Hot Item      |    7
12          | Tea           |   11
14          | Samusa        |    6
```

If I give category id is 7, I want the output as

```
category_id | category_name | category_parent_id
7           | Liquid        |    5
8           | Soft Drinks   |    7
11          | Hot Item      |    7
9           | Pepsi         |    8
10          | 7up           |    8
12          | Tea           |   11
15          | Can(100Ml)    |   10
16          | Can(250ML)    |   10
```

We need to list all subcategories of category id 7  and its subcategories in recursive mode.

Comment: Have you tried to solve this problem yourself yet?  The best way to learn SQL is by practicing it

Comment: Welcome to SO. In addition to @TimBiegeleisen message: Next time you ask a database related question provide `create table` and `insert` statements. It is always appropriate to show you tried something before asking the question, so that we can see where exactly you're struggling.

Comment: Where would items 15 and 16 come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html):

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
  mapping(category_parent_id,category_id,category_name) AS (
   SELECT category_parent_id,category_id,category_name FROM t
   UNION 
   SELECT mapping.category_parent_id, t.category_id, t.category_name FROM mapping, t
     WHERE mapping.category_id = t.category_parent_id
) SELECT category_id, category_name FROM mapping WHERE category_parent_id = 7;

 category_id | category_name 
-------------+---------------
           8 | Soft Drinks
          11 | Hot Item
          10 | 7up
           9 | Pepsi
          12 | Tea
(5 Zeilen)
```